# Permissions running NiFi on Windows 2012 Server

Tags: apache-nifi, windows-server-2012

At $employer we have a customer trying to run NiFi on Windows 2012 server. We have helped them configure it as a windows startup task using the Task Scheduler. I realise this may be more of a ServerFault question but there's nothing much about NiFi on there.

When this is run as user with local admin rights, it runs perfectly. When run with the user created specifically for this service (with the required "Run as a batch" permission), it starts up and then promptly shuts down with a permission denied error on a TCP connect.

Is there a specific Windows permission that is needed for NiFi to run as a batch and listen on TCP ports?

Answer (score 0):

On *nix systems, if the TCP port is below 1024, you need to run as `root`. I am not sure if this applies to Windows systems as well (surprisingly little documentation to answer this common question directly), but that could be the cause -- when run as an Administrator this works; when run as another user it fails. Can you share the explicit error you get from the `nifi-bootstrap.log` and/or `nifi-app.log` files?

Comment: It turned out to be something quite different. Make sure the windows user your customer has created has given that user write permissions to NiFi's conf directory